# Team Foundation Server 2018: Set field value on dropdown value change

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Currently working on customizing work items in Team Foundation Server.

So Bug/Product Backlog Item has the Priority field:

```
 <FIELD name="Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" type="Integer" reportable="dimension">
        <HELPTEXT>Business importance. 1=must fix; 4=unimportant.</HELPTEXT>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="2" />
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
          <LISTITEM value="1" />
          <LISTITEM value="2" />
          <LISTITEM value="3" />
          <LISTITEM value="4" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
```

Then I created a custom control for the work item deadline:

```
 <FIELD name="Deadline" refname="Custom.Controls.Deadline" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
```

What I want to do is set the value of the deadline base on the chosen priority. This should be editable if the user wishes to.

e.g. if priority is 1 deadline should be 2 day from current date,
if priority is 2 deadline should be 3 days from current date and so on.

I was able to add the field in the screen but stuck on how to make custom logic like mentioned above. Any small nudge to the right direction would greatly help.

TFS version is Team Foundation Server 2018 on premise (not Azure DevOps).

Comment: What you're trying to do looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675328/how-to-create-a-due-date-based-off-a-weekly-offset-in-tfs-custom-work-item). The workflow XML doesn't look like it supports expressions (distinct from if-this-value-then-this-constant-value) or calculated fields in any released edition; there's [an open DeveloperCommunity idea](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365423/support-calculated-fields-in-tfs.html) for this in ADO that currently lists as being On Roadmap.

Comment: Hi TheProvost, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. There's not any build-in solution here. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for vote or  marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

First to say, there is no build in due-date field for Bug/Product Backlog Item.  Actually the comment is only half correct.

It's not hard to use a combination of *WHEN* conditions and *COPY* rules to [Automatically change a field based on another in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790619/automatically-change-a-field-based-on-another-in-tfs) .

But that value is statically. What you need is a **dynamic work item field** (item start date+ x days). It need to calculate a field, which is not available at present:

> **Support for calculated fields and roll-ups**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365423/support-calculated-fields-in-tfs.html

Otherwise, you have to use [TFSAggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator). This plugin will allow you to calculate the fields.

Example: [Calculate Fields](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Policy-Examples#calculated-field)